# Let us flag answer comments too!

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, comment-flags

I have no idea whether this is a *bug* - something's broken - or a feature request for a missing feature that should be there, so I'm tentatively tagging this as *both.*

On Android App 1.0.24, we have the ability to flag comments. That's great! However, we can only do so for comments on a question. There is no option to flag a comment on an answer. Those need flagging too sometimes, so could we have the option to do that too?

### Options for a question comment

[image: there's a flag option]

### Options for an answer comment

[image: there isn't a flag option]

[image: nooooooo!]

Comment: +1 just for "NOOOOOOOOOO!!!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in next build (1.0.25), we had added a `can_flag` attribute to comments from the API, but I forgot to add it to the API filter used for answers.